# how to setup lazy loaded routes using require.context in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, routes, lazy-loading

How may we setup lazy loaded routes using require.context in Vue.js, like below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const app = require.context('../views/app', false, /\.vue$/).keys()
const pub = require.context('../views/public', false, /\.vue$/).keys()
const wip = require.context('../wip', false, /\.vue$/).keys()

const routes = []

app.forEach(k => {
  const key = k.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')
  const o = {
    path: `/${key}`,
    name: `${key}`,
    meta: { layout: 'app-shell' },
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "`${key}`" */ `../views/app/${key}.vue`)
  }
  routes.push(o)
})

pub.forEach(k => {
  const key = k.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')
  const o = {
    path: `/${key}`,
    name: `${key}`,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "`${key}`" */ `../views/public/${key}.vue`)
  }
  routes.push(o)
})

wip.forEach(k => {
  const key = k.replace(/(\.\/|\.vue)/g, '')
  const o = {
    path: `/${key}`,
    name: `${key}`,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "`${key}`" */ `../wip/${key}.vue`)
  }
  routes.push(o)
})

console.log(routes)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

The routes look okay in the console:

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {path: "/catalogue", name: "catalogue", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
1: {path: "/companies", name: "companies", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
2: {path: "/dashboard", name: "dashboard", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
3: {path: "/inventory", name: "inventory", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
4: {path: "/media", name: "media", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
5: {path: "/outlets", name: "outlets", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
6: {path: "/profile", name: "profile", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
7: {path: "/readings", name: "readings", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
8: {path: "/reports", name: "reports", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
9: {path: "/sales", name: "sales", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
10: {path: "/users", name: "users", meta: {…}, component: ƒ}
11: {path: "/about", name: "about", component: ƒ}
12: {path: "/forgot", name: "forgot", component: ƒ}
13: {path: "/home", name: "home", component: ƒ}
14: {path: "/login", name: "login", component: ƒ}
15: {path: "/demo1", name: "demo1", component: ƒ}
16: {path: "/demo2", name: "demo2", component: ƒ}
17: {path: "/demo3", name: "demo3", component: ƒ}
18: {path: "/demo4", name: "demo4", component: ƒ}
19: {path: "/test", name: "test", component: ƒ}
```

The app starts-up fine, but no page components/ contents are being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

can you solve your problems with this option in your code:

```
const app = require.context('../views/app', false, /\.vue$/,'lazy').keys()
```

[documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)

webpack option